# Android webview custom JS not get message from postMessage call

Tags: android, android-webview

I use my nodejs server with passport to provide 3rd party auth.  I setup a WebView on my Anrdroid client to load the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="file:///android_asset/oauth.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

With this javascript:

```
Android.callit('Loaded javascript file');

window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  Android.callit('got message event');

  authWindow.close();
}, false);

var authWindow = window.open("https://myserver/twitter/signin", "");
```

After successful auth to a third party server my nodejs server redirects to a page like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>window.opener.postMessage({"auth":true}, '*');</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Activity that starts the webview:

```
public class OAuthActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.oauth);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "Android");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView webView, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/oauth.html");
    }

    public class JSInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void callit(String with) {
            Log.i("TEST", with);
        }
    }
}
```

So why is the 'message' event never firing?

As a note I have done this in a browser and it works fine.  Just not when I try and use it in an android webview.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm stuck on the same problem. I'm using postMessage to implement crossPageChannel communication (using Google Closure) and I see the postMessage calls but the 'message' event isn't firing

Answer (score 1):

Above code will work fine if you add escape characters in above JSON as

```
window.opener.postMessage({\"auth\":true}, \"*\");
```

Comment: Here's a comprehensive example complete with a download link to a working example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753104/how-do-you-use-webmessageport-as-an-alternative-to-addjavascriptinterface/60292598#60292598