# Detect available memory inside of a WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, google-chrome, android-webview

I'm building an app that contains a `WebView` that runs some JavaScript code. That JavaScript code is quite allocation heavy and can require a lot of memory.

Sometimes, the amount of required memory exceeds the amount JavaScript can require and crashes the Chromium process of the WebView which crashes my app.

I listen to `onMemoryTrim` in my application - but it is never called in this scenario on devices with more than 1GB of memory. (Not even with `TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_LOW`).

Is there any way I could detect my WebView is running low on memory and either kill it or let it know (so it can free memory)?

I've tried polling `performance.memory` but it did not work. The following script crashes the WebView if executed in it:

```
var a = [];

var kek = () => {
  var b = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024 * 2; i++) b.push(Math.random());
  return b;
}

var ival = setInterval(() => {
  let m = performance.memory;
  if(m.jsHeapSizeLimit - m.usedJSHeapSize < 1e5) {
    console.log("Memory limited")
  } else {
    a.push(kek());
  }
});
```

Is there any way to detect memory is about to run out so I can handle it gracefully without the app crashing?

Comment: `onTrimMemory()` is called based on overall lifecycle events and the amount of free *system RAM*. Your problem would appear to be tied to some sort of process limit (e.g., standard app heap limit), and I would not expect `onTrimMemory()` to be invoked for such scenarios.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, I hadn't realized these were system-wide triggered hooks. It appears that Chrome's JavaScript's limit is the one at fault here. To be completely frank - this is because [Chrome leaks](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=749482) and when it reaches some limit - it crashes (with my app). My X in this XY problem is Chrome not crashing or having a way to catch it in my app and not crash it - although I'm interested in how to measure memory usage from a purely curious PoC as well.

Comment: @CommonsWare and apparently 8.0 introduces a way to recover from X - https://developer.android.com/preview/features/managing-webview.html#termination-handle

Comment: same here..my heap is getting exhausted..i want to know the js memory allocation..Something of this sought https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have discussed this with the Chromium team and the Android team and at the moment (they think and I believe them) that **this is impossible**.

> Sometimes, the amount of required memory exceeds the amount JavaScript can require and crashes the Chromium process of the WebView which crashes my app.

You can however catch out of memory crashes in Android 8.0+ using [the new termination handle API](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/managing-webview.html#termination-handle). So this works around my problem by not having to check the available memory required in the first place.

By overriding `onRenderProcessGone` - we get to catch the bug and recreate the WebView.

Comment: How to talk to the android team? is there a convenient way? I am seeing weird issue with webview on note9.

Comment: @003 Either: contribute enough to related open source so you know them ahead of time OR try cold-emails (like getting their emails from the commit log and sending emails and see if they answer). I've had both alternatives work for me. Also keep in mind chromium-dev is still mildly active.

The chance for getting help with a webview on a note9 is virtually 0 because it's likely not an Android or Chromium issue if it doesn't reproduce on a vanilla Android/Chromium install